# Use a Component as NPM Package Angular6

Tags: angular, npm, angular6

I am a beginner to Angular6. I tried to use Angular5-Csv for downloading CSV file.

So I used the below statements :

**Installation :**

```
>  npm install --save angular5-csv
```

**Then i have imported the above :**

```
> import { Angular5Csv } from 'angular5-csv/dist/Angular5-csv';
```

*

> ***The components using Angular5-csv is pointing to /dist folder instead of an npm package. I want to add as an npm package. Any one
>   can help me please.***

*

Comment: Can you please share the link of that plugin so I will review it and get back to you? Also, Can you please describe more about your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears that the angular package that your using has since been updated since the [npmjs page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular5-csv) was created and the description has not been updated.

That being said

```
import { Angular5Csv } from 'angular5-csv/dist/Angular5-csv';
```

is pointing to a package, however it is pointing to a subfolder called **dist** inside of the package.

Alternatively, I also noticed on that npmjs page that the [github](https://github.com/alhazmy13/angular-csv-ext#readme) links to something named slightly different but appears to have the same features.

So if it really matters that you don't have dist in the name of the import you could instead do:

```
npm install --save angular-csv-ext
```

and then use the following import:

```
import { AngularCsv } from 'angular-csv-ext/Angular-csv';
```

Here's an example of my component that exports CSV data on load:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularCsv } from 'angular-csv-ext/Angular-csv';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void 
  {
    var data = [
      {
        name: "Test 1",
        age: 13,
        average: 8.2,
        approved: true,
        description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
      },
      {
        name: 'Test 2',
        age: 11,
        average: 8.2,
        approved: true,
        description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
      },
      {
        name: 'Test 4',
        age: 10,
        average: 8.2,
        approved: true,
        description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
      },
    ];
    new AngularCsv(data, 'My Report');
  }
  title = 'test';

}
```

Comment: Yes.. The one was pointing to Dist subfolder .I tried the above plugin. It works fine for me. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose its import is

```
import { Angular5Csv } from 'angular5-csv/Angular5-csv'
```

from following link 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular5-csv'. Right?

Comment: The above import didn't work . Because the component is under DIST subfolder. I think they mistyped or didnt update the site there .

Comment: OK... finally you got the answer